# Как преобразовать текст bash

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, grep

Необходимо 
Преобразовать текст, обрамленный в звездочки, в курсив. Не трогать текст в двойных
звездочках (жирный).
Примеры:

```
*this is italic*" => <em>this is italic</em>
**bold text (not italic)** => **bold text (not italic)**
```

Но используя

```
grep ^['\*']this text2_1 | tr "\*" "<i>"
```

Получаю

```
<this is italic<" => <em>this is italic</em>
```

Почему не

```
<i>this is italic</i>" => <em>this is italic</em>
```

И Как сделать закрывающий тег `</i>` ?

Comment: Я вижу, что вы на 123 меняете. Как вы тег <i> пытаетесь получить - не показано. А grep ничего не меняет, он только ищет. `tr` понятное дело просто транслирует, он вам не подходит. `sed` бы справился, но у него регулярки слабые, а командами муторно и сложная комбинация выйдет.  Если `perl` можно использовать, то лучше им.

Comment: В рамках bash , исправил...

Comment: tr меняет не регулярку на значении, а посимвольно, первый символ из первого параметра на первый символ из второго - * меняется только на <

Comment: Ну `sed` это такое же средство как tr, так что из bash доступно. `perl` доступен практически на всех nix системах, кроме каких нибудь встроеных в роутеры и т.п. где памяти совсем мало и да, "программа" на perl будет выглядеть как ваш grep, т.е. занимать одну строку в bash скрипте. Вот я и спрашиваю, у вас perl есть ?

Comment: А как еще можно ?

Comment: Кстати, а что там кавычка делает после `*` - это как раз признак окончания италика. Или надо первую зведочку менять на <i>, а следующую на </i>. И условие, что италик начинается с самого начала строки (вы так grep напиали) всегда соблюдается или надо в любом месте строки, менять каждую четную звездочку на <i> (при условии конечно что bold нет)

Comment: Видимо да, флаг окончания

Comment: Короче `perl -pe 's%(?<!\*)\*([^*]+?)\*"?%<i>$1</i>%' text2_1` Сделает то что вы хотите. кавычка в конце не обязательна. Если обязательна, вопросительный знак после нее уберите. Ну и поставьте ^ если надо именно с начала строки.

Comment: или так `sed -r 's/(^|[^*])\*([^*]+)\*/<i>\2<\/i>/g' test2_1`

Comment: @NikolaTesla Спасибо большое, можно переводить в ответ. Но подскажите пожалуйста как читать данную регулярку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обсуждении было указано, что **grep** не обязателен, на самом деле нужен **bash**. Поэтому ниже вариант с использованием **sed**.

`sed -r 's/(^|[^*])\*([^*]+)\*/\1<i>\2<\/i>/g' test2_1`

общий вид регулярного выражения замены `s/<что ищем>/<на что меняем>/g`

`<что ищем>` читать примерно так:

- `(^|[^*])` = "начало строки" или "не звездочка" **(вхождение `\1`)**
- `\*` = за ними звездочка
- `([^*]+)` = за ней набор любых символов, но не звездочка, то есть, текст в котором нет звездочки, текст до первой звездочки **(вхождение `\2`)**
- `\*` = потом звездочка

То есть, если нашлась такая последовательность `("не звездочка") + * + (текст) + *`, то  берем **(вхождение `\1`)** и **(вхождение `\2`)** и собираем из них результат: `("не звездочка") + <i> + (текст) + </i>`

P.S.: при переносе из комментариев внес правку, в результирующей последовательности должно остаться вхождение `\1`

Comment: В общем здорово (за описание +1), но все же наверное не всегда работает (или это "не баг, а фича"?)  `*dhdhhd**hhdhdh*` преобразуется в `<i>dhdhhd</i>*hhdhdh*`

Comment: @avp  наличие впереди только одной звездочки является условием регулярки, а тут перед второй частью идет две звездочки, что не попадает под условие. Разрешать подобные конфликты, мне кажется проще всего в несколько шагов преобразований. Сначала заменить все `**текст**`, потом все `*текст*` без проверок того, что идет перед или после таких вхождений.

Comment: На самом деле я не знаю, какую регулярку тут надо написать. Но, если регулярка для bold будет идеологически той же, что для italic, то  два шага преобразований для `*a**b*` все равно не сработают.

Comment: Первым шагом меняется `**текст**` (`s/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/<b>\1<\/b>/g`) и с таким примером ничего не происходит. Вторым шагом `s/\*([^*]+)\*/<i>\1<\/i>/g` без проверки знаков "до и после". Получим два италика в данном примере `<i>a</i><i>b</i>`

Comment: Да, если принять такой "двухэтапный" алгоритм, то все ОК. Для общности (наверное ТС и не требуется) осталось не реагировать на экранированные (\\*) звездочки.